# How to get UITextField text length for different tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have four `UITextField` tagged with 1 to 4. Now I want to get the text length of each text field. I want to get this information in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. I know with this `textField.text.length` I can get the text field text length and with this `textField.tag == 1` I can get the particular tagged `UITextField`. But Is it possible to get the text length for a particular tagged `UITextField`? Using it's tagged? If yes, How?

A lot of thanks in advance.
**I don't want to use the instance of my `UITextField`**

Comment: First assign different tag value to each of your textfield. Than in shouldChangeCharactersInRange , get textField.tag value and compare with assigned tag value.

Comment: @Tulon i had try to help you.i am not expecting this from you.

Comment: Dear @rmaddy, Is it possible to delete this post?

Comment: @Tulon i answer helped you still you not accepted it and not uprooted for it. what is the reason only because of rmaddy. if was trying to help you. replay me as early as possible..

Comment: @Tulon First you accepted my answer. what happen again ??? Replay please

Answer (score 1):

YES, you can do it by getting all the subviews of you main view & then you can iterate loop

```
for(UIView *v in [self.view allSubViews])
{
     if([v isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
     {
         ** Here you can add you logic to check the tag of all text field & can get the length accordingly **
     }
}
```

Let me know if you need anymore clarification on it..

Comment: It's too much for that little need I presume. :(
Any ways thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @Tulon I think this is the appropriate answer. As this gets your All the TextField lengths simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use the instance of my
>   UITextField

Then how do you expect to access its properties? Just assign a tag to each `UITextField` and access its properties in the delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if(textField.tag == 0)
        NSLog(@"%i", textField.text.length);

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I also think the same thing. There is no other way but using instance `UITextField`.

Comment: @Nikita i have edited your answer because you have write wrong method and you reject my edit. why??

Comment: @AshokLondhe, your edit was incorrect as you wrote, `string.length`, will always return 1. The value of `string` will be the last character typed into the text field. That is why I rejected it.

Comment: @Nikita I have not write this statement i just corrected your method. you missed : in your method check it first.

Comment: @AshokLondhe I didn't reject that. But thanks, I will edit it now.

Comment: @AshokLondhe I did not reject your edit for the method correction.

Comment: @Nikita i have helped you and you are down voting for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
 switch (textField.tag) {
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"textfield1=%lu", (unsigned long)textField.text.length);

        break;

    case 2:
         NSLog(@"textfield2=%lu", (unsigned long)textField.text.length);
        break;

    case 3:
        NSLog(@"textfield3=%lu", (unsigned long)textField.text.length);

        break;

    case 4:
        NSLog(@"textfield4=%lu", (unsigned long)textField.text.length);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: perfecto. :)
Dhanneybad my friend. :)

Comment: How is this useful? It gets the length of the exact same text field in every case.

Comment: @rmaddy it will gives every textfields length. based on tag. you can check it.

Comment: You'll get the same result with one line of code. No need for a switch statement to get the ,length of the text field.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right. but your thinking is different my is different. so i use it which i like. Thanks you your suggestion it  helps me.

Comment: Why would you use a pointless switch statement when a single line of code would do the same thing? There is no way this answer solves the question. I don't understand why the OP accepted this answer.

Comment: @rmaddy if you have good answer then why not you posted it. why are you doing like mad.

Comment: @rmaddy you have down voted for me. but it doesn't matter for me. i not posting my answers for voting . i know you have lot of knowledge but it doesn't mean that you can apply it anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78282/discussion-between-ashok-londhe-and-rmaddy).